# FB.getLoginStatus is not called when doing a page refresh (Facebook Javascript SDK)

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to implement a webpage that connects with a user's Facebook profile, using their Javascript SDK. 
Following their initial documentation:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: '[my-appid]', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  //Check if user is logged-in to facebook:
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.session) {
         // Here I use some FB.api functions 
         // and get some data I need about the user's facebook profile,
         // and make same changes to the document html accordingly...
     }

  });
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); 
  e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

</script>
```

The FB.getLoginStatus function is written right after FB.init, as they recommend on doing.
Everything works ok when I load the page for the first time. But, if I hit refresh (F5) - 
then the **FB.getLoginStatus** never gets called! and thus the required information is not gathered.
If I put an 'alert' right after FB.init - it works and I see it.
If I put an 'alert' inside FB.getLoginStatus then it does not work.
If I do a "no-cache refresh" (with Ctrl-F5 instead of F5) - then everything works.

Why is that? and how can I make it work as it should?

Thanks.

Comment: I am having this exact problem, but only on Safari (both desktop and iPad).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when trying to figure this out. FB.init is asynchronous, the alert is causing enough of a delay to get everything initialized. FB.getLoginStatus is most likely being called, but is erroring out. Do you see any errors in your error console? You may see an error about calling FB.getLoginStatus before init.

The other possibility is that you have xfbml set to true. Facebook seems to do a double initialization sometimes, causing your call to init to fail. Try setting xfbml to false. If you need to render FBML on the page, render the specific elements.

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('idOfElement'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not get any errors at all in the javascript console. I also tried setting xfbml to false - and it still didn't help... :\

Comment: I just checked my own code. Looks like I resorted to calling FB.init at the bottom of the page, not within fbAsyncInit. Seems that fbAsyncInit doesn't always fire off.

Comment: My testings actually show that fbAsyncInit is always called... and also FB.init (at least, an alert after it is getting called). - it is only FB.getLoginStatus that sometimes doesn't get called for me...
I will try moving some of the code to the bottom of the page, see if it will help though, thanks...

Comment: where would you place this? `FB.xfbml.parse(document.getElementById('fb-send'));`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not "FB.getLoginStatus never gets called".  Your code calls FB.getLoginStatus().  It is FB.getLoginStatus() that never calls your response function.

Open another tab and go to facebook.com.  If your browser is logged into a facebook, try logging out, then try to reproduce the problem.

You might have this problem if your browser is logged into facebook as a test account. Or, an account that doesn't have permission to view an application that is in sandbox mode.  Logging out of facebook should solve the problem for these cases.

I've seen the problem in firefox and when it happens, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Disabling sandbox mode fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I am having this problem (with Safari and Firefox only), but I am not logged in and my app is not in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but I was experiencing the same race condition because I was inadvertently replacing the `fb-root` div during client-side template rendering. Make sure this div is present when your page loads and that it isn't being touched by any other code.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, fbAsyncInit and therefore getLoginStatus that was inside that, was not being called when i hit ctrl+F5
After a lot of debugging i found out that the issue was that i didnt have the javascript sdk code in the correct sequence as the Facebook example suggests: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web
I had the fb-root div and the code for loading the sdk in the header of my page and then i was calling the fbAsync method in the footer. When i put everything together the issue was resolved:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId      : '<?php echo $appID; ?>',
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.8'
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    checkstatus(response);
});

};

/// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```